# Need code that blocks/redirects users from page after first visit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a website that has design, photos, etc on it, but I was hoping to have it set up so that a visitor may only get to a page once.

In other words, I would like, after the first visit, for the person to be redirected back to a splash page, but only have that cookie be tracked until the content on the page changes in the future.

How could I do this? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I suppose in **theory** it would be possible with raw JavaScript, but would involve not only cookies but also recurring AJAX requests on every single page on your website, which would result in massive overheads. You'd be far better off setting a flag in a database for returning users, assuming they have to log in to see the photos in the first place. Then you could set all the flags to `0` when you update the page.

Comment: Each browser "request" is actually 2 requests: one for the page and another for favicon.